# Node package.json script not running on windows - Cannot find module yarn.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, package, package.json

I would like to run multiple scripts one after another so I created scripts in `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "predeploy": "yarn build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
  "deploy-windows": "yarn build; gh-pages -d build"
 }
```

On Mac it is working fine so if I type `yarn deploy` it runs `yarn build` and `gh-pages -d build` after.

On windows I have a problem because I get this error:

[image]

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
}
```

How can I fix that? When I run `yarn build` and `gh-pages -d build` separately it works fine but I cannot run them in one script on Windows.

Comment: did you install `yarn`?

Comment: Can you put the text of the error into your question? I can't read your screenshot.

Comment: I wrote that I can run `yarn build` so I have it

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas `Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.n.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)   
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []`

Comment: Also usually when chaining multiple scripts, I've used `&&` instead of `;`. Eg. `"deploy-windows": "yarn build && gh-pages -d build"`. Though you could even invoke the other scripts, which would cut down on the duplication: `"deploy-windows": "npx run predeploy && npx run deploy"`.

Comment: Is the `yarn.n.js` a typo, or is the `.n` really in there? On the screenshot, it doesn't look like that. PS: i also have a `yarn.js` (and a `yarn`) file in the folder it searches in.

Comment: @ASDFGerte typo, sorry.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I tried `&&` aslso but it doesn't work, I still get this error.

Comment: What about invoking the predeploy and deploy scripts from the deploy-windows script?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I got `Error: Cannot find module 'D:\path\predeploy'` when I do `"deploy-windows": "npx run predeploy && npx run deploy"`

Comment: One last question: how did you install yarn? The path in your error says it's looking for a global npm package (eg. installed via `npm i -g`). Is that how you installed yarn or did you use some other method? The fact that you can run yarn from the commandline just means that it's on your path.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas to be fair I do not remember that, I run `npm i -g yarn` but it didn't help

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas any other solutions?